# An abstract method forced to be static in java

Tags: java, class

I'm not sure if the title is right but basically I have this piece of code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ArrEmployee.size(); ++i){
        ArrEmployee.get(i);
        double provTax = ProvincialTax.calculateTax(ArrEmployee.get(i));
```

And this arrayList:

```
    List<Employee> ArrEmployee = new ArrayList<>(); //  array for employee objects
```

And the ProvincialTax class is like this:

```
public class ProvincialTax extends Deductions { // deductions is an abstract class with the abstract method calculateTax()

public double calculateTax(Employee employee) {

    if (employee.getAnnualGrossSalary() < 41495){
        return employee.getAnnualGrossSalary()*0.16;
    }
    else if (employee.getAnnualGrossSalary() < 82985){
        return employee.getAnnualGrossSalary()*0.20;
    }
    else if(employee.getAnnualGrossSalary() < 100970){
        return employee.getAnnualGrossSalary()*0.24;
    }
    else
        return employee.getAnnualGrossSalary()*0.2575;

}
```

}

So basically my arrayList ArrEmployee stores Employee objects that have the variables:

```
     public long EmployeeNumber;
     public String EmployeeName;
     public String LastName;
     public double HoursWorked;
     public double HourlyWage;
```

And the `HoursWorked` and `HourlyWage` are used to calculate `AnnualGrossSalary` used in my ProvincialTax class. With my for loop, I'm trying to calculate the provincial tax for each object inside the `ArrEmployee`, but it keeps asking me to make the method `calculateTax()` static, but it's supposed to override an abstract method?

How do I bypass this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't that you should *make* your method static, the problem is that you're invoking the method as if it was static, which you shouldn't do. The problem is in the line:

```
double provTax = ProvincialTax.calculateTax(ArrEmployee.get(i));
```

Which instance of `ProvincialTax` do you want to invoke it on? Invoke it on *that* instance.

```
ProvincialTax taxInstance = ...; // Get an instanceof of ProvincialTax
double provTax = taxInstance.calculateTax(ArrEmployee.get(i));
```

Answer (score 2):

Without further evidence and the fact that you're not using preferred naming conventions, `ProvincialTax.calculateTax` appears to be trying to call the `calculateTax` via the `ProvincialTax` `Class` and not a instance of it...

```
ProvincialTax provincialTax = new ProvincialTax();
for(int i = 0; i < ArrEmployee.size(); ++i){
    double provTax = provincialTax.calculateTax(ArrEmployee.get(i));
}
```

You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others